# Could someone please help me by listening to this speaker and telling me what do you think he is saying?

Tags: meaning

This lecturer is [speaking](https://youtu.be/zH2s4XSEWO0?t=425)

> that's the idea, the more data I give it, the better the program is, that's why we call it learning.
>
> let
>   me go through a little bit let's just **???** and give you a
>   little bit before we get dive into how to do this and a little bit of history of how this all started and where I came from.

I listened the part marked ??? many times and cannot get what This lecturer is speaking.

Could someone please help to listen this part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He is saying

> let's just [walk down **memory lane**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/memory%20lane) and give you a little bit before ...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What does "walk down memory lane" mean?

Comment: Please see the link I provided in the answer. "Memory Lane" is spoken of as if it is an actual place, but it is a metaphor.

Answer (score 0):

He's saying " ... let's just **walk down memory lane** and give you ...".

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What does "walk down memory lane" mean?

Comment: @singularli Have you Googled this phrase? What did you find on Google?